# I'm installing Ubuntu, but what am I doing wrong?

Tags: system-installation, windows, lenovo, usb-installation

Here's my problem. I'm trying to install ubuntu, but I keep getting

```
"Failed to create a file system - The ext4 File system creation partition #2 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sdb) failed."
```

I plug the usb in, I wait for it to install, I select option where I can go ahead and erase stuff on the hard drive and install, but the progress bar refuses to make any progress.

What is going on?

[image]

Comment: Have you coincidentally had any storage problems or unexplained crashes on the older operating system that you are wiping?

Comment: What brand/model system? What version of Ubuntu? Can you use gparted to create partitions on sdb? Then use Something Else and change to select partition(s).